# sqlite3: INSERT OR IGNORE OR UPDATE for multiple unique columns

Tags: sqlite

My *simplified* database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(hash TEXT, timestamp DATE, value1 TEXT, value2 REAL, UNIQUE(hash, timestamp));
```

The `hash` column is an MD5 hash of everything in the row.

**Problem**

A script will put the following example row in the table:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES("7494ab07987ba112bd5c4f9857ccfb3f", "2019-12-19", "temp", 1);
```

Then the script will run an hour later and `value2` may or may not have changed. This is equivalent to `hash` changing or remaining the same. If the hash has changed for the given date I want to update the row with the new values.

For a concrete example, below are the three possible statements that could run 1 hour after the statement above.

```
(case 1) INSERT INTO my_table VALUES("7494ab07987ba112bd5c4f9857ccfb3f", "2019-12-19", "temp", 1);

    or...

(case 2) INSERT INTO my_table VALUES("64a5dcbe3f4af29ca58b8d99b1c3a9f2", "2019-12-19", "temp", 2);

    or...

(case 3) INSERT INTO my_table VALUES("514292c37cc92b2ee2cd797328bed2d5", "2019-12-20", "temp 2", 3);
```

1. If (case 1) runs, the `INSERT` statement should be `IGNORE`d.
2. If (case 2) runs, the `INSERT` statement should be an `UPDATE`.
3. If (case 3) runs, the `INSERT` statement should run normally.

For a given timestamp (new_timestamp) which may or may not already be in my table, and hash (new_hash) I need a statement that will do something like this:

```
if new_timestamp in my_table:
    if new_hash == old_hash:
        IGNORE
    else:
        UPDATE
else:
    INSERT
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The unique key for the row is the `timestamp` contrary to what my initial question said. The timestamp will not ever change. I will know some other value in the row changed by watching the hash, but I use the timestamp to ensure I am back in the right row. Case 2 could be a REPLACE for all I care, but if the hash changes for a given timestamp I do not want to create a new row for that timestamp. The timestamp will always be unique.

Comment: Look into the UPSERT clause at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html.

Comment: But there is at least one major problem with the algorithm you describe.  The unique key includes the hash, but **if the hash changes there is no way to identify the original row**... *unless you also supply the original hash to the statement or provide another primary key independent of the hash.* But if you already know the original hash along with the new hash, you could enforce the conditional logic in the host code.  In fact, sqlite is designed to be reliant upon on the host code, hence no stored procedures and no general conditional and looping logic outside the standard SQL statements.

Comment: In other words, why should case 2 be an update?  There is nothing in the case 2 statement to indicate that it is an update rather than a new record just like case 3.  It doesn't matter that it has the same date, or that heuristically it looks similar to case 1.  Strictly according to the table schema it is its own new record.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The unique key for the row is the timestamp. That will not ever change. I will know some other value in the row changed by watching the hash, but I use the timestamp to ensure I am back in the right row.

Case 2 could be a REPLACE for all I care, but if the hash changes for a given timestamp I do not want to create a new row for that timestamp. The timestamp will always be unique.

Comment: That's good information, but this contradicts the schema in the question:  `UNIQUE(hash, timestamp)`.  Especially for crucial information like this, the question should be edited and clarified and/or corrected... not just left as a comment.  And this isn't just a matter of being picky, rather the [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) clause will not function properly if the unique constraint is not properly defined, so the schema needs to be fixed also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the timestamp is defined as unique (which does not match the current question details), addition of the [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) clause will satisfy all three cases:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (hash, timestamp, value1, value2) 
   VALUES ('7494ab07987ba112bd5c4f9857ccfb3f', '2019-12-19', 'temp', 1)
   ON CONFLICT (timestamp) DO UPDATE
   SET hash = excluded.hash, value1 = excluded.value1, value2 = excluded.value2
   WHERE hash != excluded.hash;
```

(FYI, the standard string delimiter is a single quote `'`, not double quotes `"`.)

Comment: I see. My mistake for including the `UNIQUE(hash, timestamp)`. I was under the impression both would need to be in there. Just to be sure, only `UNIQUE(timestamp)` is needed correct? I tested that out and it seemed to work just fine. Thank you.